# Eloquent eager loading specific columns

Tags: laravel

I have two models :Product and category
which are linked by a one-to-many relationship. A category has several products. I would like to select specific columns from each model.

Here is the query I have, but I have all the columns with category_id, but I want the category name instead of id. How can I do that. Thank you in advance.

**here is the method in controller**

```
$products = Product::with('categories:id,name')->get();

    if ($products) {
        $response = ['api_status' => 1, 'api_message' => 'success', 'data' => $products];
        return response()->json($response);
    } else {
        $response = ['api_status' => 0, 'api_message' => 'Error'];
        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

**Here is category model**

```
class Categorie extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable =['name','redirect'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(product::class);
    }
}
```

**and the product model is:**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'detail', 'img',
        'categorie_id', 'onSale',
        'costPrice', 'inStock', 'salePrice'
    ];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categorie::class);
    }
}
```

here is the response:[image]

Comment: what columns do you want?

Comment: Hello  @lagbox , I want to select all columns of product model and name of the category

Comment: you will need to select the name and id so eloquent can match up the records, so you have to at least have those 2 fields selected for 'categories'

Comment: Ok @lagbox i try that but i got the same result

Answer (score 1):

You can select particular fields from the relationship but you always need to select any keys involved in the relationship:

```
$products = Product::with('categories:id,name')->get();
```

Now each Product has its 'categories' loaded and those Category models only have the `id` and `name` fields.

Importantly:

The relationship `categories` is named incorrectly, it should be `categorie` in this case as the foreign key on Product is `categorie_id` and it is a singular relationship, it does not return multiple results.

```
Product::with('categorie:id,name')->get()
```

If you want to keep the name `categories` you would have to define the foreign key used when defining the `belongsTo`relationship, the second argument.

If you need to transform the structure of any of this that is a different thing and you will be walking into transformers or an API Resource.

Not sure how you want your data to look but this is the structure you will have by eager loading records, so if you need a different structure then what you get you will have to show an example.

Comment: no I don't want to transform the answer @lagbox, that's what you explained I want. But strangely it doesn't load the category names.

Comment: doesn't load the category names on what? its a relationship, the category names are on the Category models

Comment: Yes the category name is on the category model

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: I have updated the post with the received answer, the problem, I have category id and no name.

Comment: you won't have a category name being a part of the Product ... it is part of the relationship which is a different model ... also your relationship should be named `categorie` not `categories` as this isn't a plural relationship it is a belongsTo ... which means eloquent won't be matching up the records correctly because it will look for the wrong key because the relationship is not named correctly (that is how it determines the key to use, based off the name and the foreign key is `categorie_id`)

Comment: Okay I see, I'll change that. Thanks for the corrections

Comment: with that adjustment you should start to see the 'categorie' property have the related object

Comment: I tested this code, it works perfectly as I wanted. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the output of your model I'd suggest using an [API resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources). This will give you more granular control about how a resource is returned by the API. A resource is also the best point to modify certain values.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'detail' => $this->detail,
            'img' => $this->img,
            'category_id' => $this->categorie->name,
            'category_name' => $this->categorie->name,
            'onSale' => $this->onSale,
            'costPrice' => $this->costPrice,
            'inStock' => $this->inStock,
            'salePrice' => $this->salePrice,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
            'deleted_at' => $this->deleted_at,
            'categories' => $this->categories ?? null,
        ];
    }
}
```

This way you can manually specify which values your response should have.

In your controller you can include the populated array in your response by manually filling the `toArray` method with the current request object or just by using the `resolve` method which basically does the previous task for you:

```
$response = [
    'api_status' => 1,
    'api_message' => 'success',
    'data' => ProductResource::collection($products)->resolve()
];
```

Comment: Ok thanks @Dan for the suggestion, I'll test that too.

Comment: Great, I hope it helps. Be aware that my code's not tested at all.

Comment: I tested this code, it works perfectly as I wanted. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helped.